# What exactly is Jakarta ee

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I don't seem to find something online expect the fact that java ee stops and we can't use name right so we renamed it as Jakarta ee and that's ok but I still don't know if there any difference between Jakarta ee and java ee 8 why should I use Jakarta ee and not java ee 8 and on top of that I can't figure out where can I find Jakarta ee to start using it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is just the specification for Java Enterprise Edition going forward.

Oracle moved the JCP process to the Eclipse Foundation, but since Oracle still owns the Java trademark, Eclipse renamed it to *Jakarta EE*.

This blog might give you some more insight:
https://eclipse-foundation.blog/2018/02/26/and-the-name-is/

Comment: but is Jakarta ee up I mean can I use it like I can use java ee 8 right now

Comment: It is just the specification. You won't *use it* as such. The specification process for new EE standard APIs will go through Eclipse Foundation instead of Oracle. Then Eclipse Glassfish will probably be the first to implement the new shiny APIs, followed by JBoss/Wildfly and the rest in due time.

Comment: so that means that Jakarta ee is still under development and we wait for the release to be able to use it

Comment: Well the current version of the specs in Jakarta EE is equivalent to Java EE 8. New EE specifications will be under Jakarta EE, so you won't see Java EE 9.

Comment: which jakarta version is compatible with java 10?

Comment: @Bionix1441 you mean Java SE 10? There is no reason why it shouldn't work. (You might need to include some extra libraries like jaxb that were removed from SE but thats it). I would actually use Java SE 11 not 10, since 11 is LTS and 10 is not. It depends on the server implementation too (Wildfly, Glassfish etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Jakarta EE is the name used since 2017 for the technologies previously known as Java EE.

These technologies are composed by technical specifications and open source reference implementations of a Java based platform for enterprise applications.

More details in https://jakarta.ee/

Comment: Is this still correct?

Comment: In general yes, but since the transition to the Eclipse Foundation was concluded I am providing an update to the answer. Thanks for your comment.